# Next js: open index.js on visiting '/blogs/'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my next.js project, how can I open the index.js page whenever I visit 'localhost:3000/blogs/'

The index.js file resides under 'blogs' folder.

It does open up when I visit 'localhost:3000/blogs'. But if I append a forward slash after blogs it redirects to 404 page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Next Js doesn't work like that. Based on server routes, it maps to the pages folder which we call [Dynamic Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). So if your routes is defined on server like this:

```
server.get("/blogs/*", (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, "/blogs/[index]");
    });
```

and your folder structure is like: `pages/blogs/[index].js` then only it will open your index file.

For more clarification read the link  mentioned above for `Dynamic Routing`.